# Do the elders appear in a predetermined order?

Tags: altos-adventure

I’ve noticed that elders in Alto’s Adventure appear in different colors based on their difficulty. The first elder is always red, but at further distances they’ve been green, yellow, and blue.

How many types of elders are there? Do they appear in a predetermined order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Alto's Adventure Wikia, there are 5 types of the Elders appearing in game. The Wiki also states that each next elder is a bit faster than the previous one.

The list goes like this:

- **The Red Elder**. Found at around 2,700m. Chases the player till around 4,000m.
- **The Green Elder**. Found at around 6,700m. Chases the player till around 8,400m.
- **The Yellow Elder**. Found at around 10,900m. Chases the player till around 12,600m
- **The Blue Elder**. Found at around 15,100m. Chases the player till around 17,100m.
- **The Black Elder**. Found at around 19,600m. Chases the player till around 21,600m.
- **The White Elder**. Found around 24,100m. Chases the player till around 26,100m

This is where the Wiki stops listing them, but I suppose each consecutive Elder remains the Black one.

Source: [Alto's Adventure Wikia - Elders](http://altosadventure.wikia.com/wiki/Elder(s))

Comment: I just ran into a White Elder. Can there be more of them?

Comment: @Chris During the time of posting, Alto's Adventure Wikia only had five of the elders listed, but I see Robotnik already updated my answer with the last of the elders added. Now the mystery remains whether the 7th elder is the white one again, or any different colour :) Congrats on sliding this far!